(Lee 8-12 SM) How do you find a global extension of a vector field defined on an open set?
I have a function $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{RP}^2$ given by $F(x,y) = [x,y,1]$, and some vector field $X$, and a vector field on $\mathbb{RP}^2$ given by $X(x,y) = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.
I want to find a vector field $Y$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is $F$-related to $X$.
$F$ is not surjective, but nonetheless, I of course need to check how $Y$ ought to behave on points that are in $\mathrm{im \text{ }}X$.
So, I decided to look at what $dF$ pushes vectors to. I chose the chart $(U, \phi)$ for $\mathbb{RP}^2$ where $U$ is the set of points with nonvanishing third entry, and $\phi([x,y,z]) = (\frac{x}{z}, \frac{y}{z})$ and found $dF$ to be trivial with respect to this coordinate representation.
So, I thought that whatever $Y$ should be, it should 'look like $X$ in coordinates,' whatever that means.
This is my problem. I do not believe that I understand what I am doing when I define a vector field 'in coordinates.' Let me spew out some words that may or may not clarify my current state of understanding (very little!):

The above chart is equal to the image of $F$. Therefore, I define the vector field $Y$ as follows: Given a point $p \in U$, look at its coordinate representation $(x,y)$. Then, define $Y(x,y) = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ (i.e. exactly what X is).
This defines a smooth vector field on the image of $F$. First of all, it is well defined; I am explicitly choosing a particular chart. Next, it is smooth. If I were to take some other chart instead, the smoothness should fall out of composing diffeomorphisms. (Please, if someone can confirm my understanding here, I will be much obliged. I feel uneasy about doing anything with respect to a particular coordinate representation, even if irrationally)
Extend this vector field to all of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ by some process? Clearly (admittedly, I did not check this part), I cannot simply stipulate that the above characterization $Y$ should hold with respect to any chart; it may not be well defined. If the above assumption is correct, what should I do? Define some sort of 'trivial' smooth vector fields on the other charts comprising the atlas, and then paste together with a partition of unity?

Apologies for the menial questions. I do not trust my brain to reason/interpret the textbook correctly when left to my own devices.

You have a typo. You mean a vector field $Y$ on $\Bbb RP^2$. So what happens to the vector field on $F(\Bbb R^2)$ when you consider a different coordinate patch? If you use coordinates $[1,u,v]$, how are $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$ related? What is the vector field in the $(u,v)$ coordinates?

Ah I see! I was too pessimistic about whether the obvious extension worked.

Let $\varphi_0 : U_0 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $\varphi_1: U_1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, and $\varphi_2: U_2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the three standard charts on $\mathbb{RP}^2$ (page 6 of Lee). Let's call our coordinates $[1, u, v]$, $[w, 1, z]$, and $[x,y,1]$ respectively.
We will define a global vector field on $\mathbb{RP}^2$ by defining local vector fields on each coordinate chart and then gluing them together. We can define local vector fields on the charts of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ by defining them as coordinate vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and pulling them back via the $\varphi_i$. As you rightly pointed out, since $F = \varphi_2^{-1}$ we want to define
$$X_2 = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$
to be our vector field on $U_2$ (the image of $F$).
Note that $X_2$ is not vector field on $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as it is not defined at any points of the form $[X,Y,0] \in \mathbb{RP}^2$. We want to make sure that our definition of $X_2$ can be extended to these other points. We will accomplish this by changing coordinates to the other two charts.
Let's look at $U_0 \cap U_2$. Our goal is to rewrite $X_2$ in terms of $(u,v)$ on this overlap. We have that $[1,u,v] = [\frac{1}{v}, \frac{u}{v}, 1] = [x, y, 1]$. Therefore the change of coordinate function is given by $(\varphi_2\circ\varphi_0^{-1})(u,v) = (\frac{1}{v},\frac{u}{v})$. Often we write this as $x = \frac{1}{v}$ and $y = \frac{u}{v}$.
Now we know how to replace $x$ and $y$ with $u$ and $v$, but we also need to change coordinates in the tangent vectors. This is covered in Chapter 3 of Lee in the section on changing coordinates (see Example 3.16). We compute that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} &= -\frac{y}{x^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial u} - \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\\ &= -uv \frac{\partial}{\partial u} - v^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial v}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} &= \frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\\ &= v \frac{\partial}{\partial u}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, on $U_0 \cap U_2$ we can express $X_2$ as
\begin{align*}
X_2 &= \frac{1}{v}\left(v\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right) - \frac{u}{v}\left(-uv \frac{\partial}{\partial u} - v^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)\\
&= (1+u^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial u} + uv \frac{\partial}{\partial v}
\end{align*}
Here is the key step: we define a coordinate vector field on all of $U_0$ by
$$X_0 = (1+u^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial u} + uv \frac{\partial}{\partial v}.$$
By construction, $X_0$ agrees with $X_2$ on $U_0 \cap U_2$. All of the coordinate functions are smooth in the definitions of $X_0$ and $X_2$, so $X_0$ is a smooth vector field on $U_0$ and $X_2$ is a smooth vector field on $U_2$ by Proposition 8.1 of Lee. Since $X_0$ and $X_2$ agree on $U_0 \cap U_2$, we can glue these smooth vector fields together to get a smooth vector field on $U_0 \cup U_2$. The reason we can glue follows from the definition of a vector field as a section of $\pi: TM \to M$ (sections that agree on the intersection of their domains glue to give a section on the union of their domains).
I'll leave it to you to follow the same procedure to construct a vector bundle on $U_1$ that agrees with $X_2$ on $U_1 \cap U_2$ and check that the coordinate functions are smooth. This allows you to know that $X_2$ really does extend smoothly to all of $\mathbb{RP}^2$.
More generally, one can construct a vector field on a smooth manifold $M$ by defining coordinate vector fields on each chart of $M$ and then checking that we can glue these locally defined coordinate vector fields into a global vector field. One can check that this is equivalent to defining a section of $\pi: TM \to M$. By 'checking that we can glue these local sections', what I mean is that if $\varphi: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\psi: V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are two charts of $M$ with coordinates $(x^1, \ldots, x^n)$ and $(y^1, \ldots, y^n)$ respectively, and if $$X_p = X^i(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{\varphi(p)},  \ \ \ p \in U$$ and
$$Y_p = Y^i(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}\bigg|_{\psi(p)}, \ \ \ p \in V$$
are the coordinate vector fields we defined on $U$ and $V$, then on $U \cap V$ changing coordinates will not change the vector field. Formally this means that $X_p = Y_p$ for all $p \in U \cap V$. We check this by using the change of coordinates formula for tangent vectors (page 63 of Lee)
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{\varphi(p)} = \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}(\varphi(p))\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\bigg|_{\psi(p)},$$
where $\displaystyle \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}(\varphi(p))$ is obtained from the Jacobian of the transition function $\psi \circ \varphi^{-1}$.
So we are trying to verify that
$$X^i(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{\varphi(p)} = X^i(p)\frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}(\varphi(p))\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\bigg|_{\psi(p)} = Y^j(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\bigg|_{\psi(p)}.$$
This is precisely what we checked above to guarantee that the local sections glue:
$$Y^j = X^i \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}.$$
